# All my syntax is correct, why isn't my sprite spinning?

Tags: c#, game-development, godot

I am trying to learn Godot, so I am following a tutorial. However, when I attempt to run the code, it does not work, even though all the syntax is the same as the tutorial. Could this be a technical issue? (I am using the internal Godot editor for c#)

My code is as follows:

```
using Godot;

public class Sprite : Godot.Sprite
{
    private int Speed = 400;
    private float AngularSpeed = Mathf.Pi;

    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {
        Rotation += AngularSpeed * delta;
        var velocity = Vector2.Up.Rotated(Rotation) * Speed;

        Position += velocity * delta;

    }
}
```

Comment: The obvious question is whether you have actually attached this script to the sprite in your scene

Comment: It is attached to my sprite in-scene.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code. I copied the code and attached it to a Sprite and it started spinning.. 
Guess we need more infos to help you with that. Could you for example create a sample project with the scene and provide it to us (like github or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.

The only solution i could find is to try to paste it all
into something like notepad and gedit(open res:// in file manager of choice).

Make sure the sprite has the script attached and that it is all in a Node2D root scene as seen in the attached example. Make sure that the sprite Node has that scroll icon to the right. Otherwise try reinstalling and have a look for any compile errors and warnings :)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr2x3.png)

Comment: If i went wrong please tell me please i am kinda new :)